# How a suspend function/method works under the hood in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The intent of this question is to understand how the suspending method work under the hood, and what is the significance of `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();`?

in the byte code below you will see a piece of code

```
if (var10000.resultingBlockingOp-IoAF18A((Continuation)$continuation) == var4) {
               return var4;
            }
```

where var4 is

```
Object var4 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
```

if the function returns then how coroutine will be then executed?

In the `invokeSuspend` method it is calling itself, does that mean suspending method works through recursion under the hood?

```
class CoroutineExplanatoryUseCase {
    private val coroutineExplanatoryRepo: CoroutineExplanatoryRepo = CoroutineExplanatoryRepo()

    suspend fun simpleOp() {
        coroutineExplanatoryRepo.simpleBlockingOp()
    }

    suspend fun resultingBlockingOp() {
        coroutineExplanatoryRepo.resultingBlockingOp()
    }

}
```

*Generated Bytecode*

```
public final class CoroutineExplanatoryUseCase {
   private final CoroutineExplanatoryRepo coroutineExplanatoryRepo = new CoroutineExplanatoryRepo();

   @Nullable
   public final Object simpleOp(@NotNull Continuation $completion) {
      Object var10000 = this.coroutineExplanatoryRepo.simpleBlockingOp($completion);
      return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
   }

   @Nullable
   public final Object resultingBlockingOp(@NotNull Continuation var1) {
      Object $continuation;
      label20: {
         if (var1 instanceof <undefinedtype>) {
            $continuation = (<undefinedtype>)var1;
            if ((((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != 0) {
               ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label -= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               break label20;
            }
         }

         $continuation = new ContinuationImpl(var1) {
            // $FF: synthetic field
            Object result;
            int label;

            @Nullable
            public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
               this.result = $result;
               this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               return CoroutineExplanatoryUseCase.this.resultingBlockingOp(this);
            }
         };
      }

      Object $result = ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).result;
      Object var4 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
      switch (((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            CoroutineExplanatoryRepo var10000 = this.coroutineExplanatoryRepo;
            ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label = 1;
            if (var10000.resultingBlockingOp-IoAF18A((Continuation)$continuation) == var4) {
               return var4;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            ((Result)$result).unbox-impl();
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
      }

      return Unit.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

**Note: I already know that when continuation C resumes then it will resume Continuation B and then it will resume A, the point that I am trying to understand is there are some return statements after the value matches with `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()` , if that function returns then how it will ultimately execute the rest of the branches in `switch/if`.**

**So if you can explain the step-by-step control flow, It would be great!!!**

Comment: Under some of your other questions, I provided you a link to my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679497/how-does-continuation-work-in-kotlin-coroutine/73680326#73680326 Did you read it? It pretty much answers your above questions as well.

Comment: Maybe check [this source](https://kt.academy/article/cc-under-the-hood) too.

Comment: @broot this question is to understand how it works under the hood. which may help to understand what is the problem in the earlier question. Thanks for sharing though

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexis, I am going through that article, seems promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question on how suspending works in details, is not that easy as the process is pretty complicated. As said in comments, you can read a [a blog post by Marcin Moskała](https://kt.academy/article/cc-under-the-hood) or alternatively [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679497/how-does-continuation-work-in-kotlin-coroutine/73680326#73680326).

But we can focus on your main question, i.e. what's the meaning of `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()`, why do coroutines return from functions and how is it possible they continue after returning.

**Problem**

One of the biggest challenges to implement coroutines is to make possible to suspend. By *suspending* we mean waiting inside a function without occupying any thread. We need to be aware this is technically impossible in JVM, JavaScript and most other runtimes. These runtimes simply don't support such functionality and we can't add such support just like that.

**Solution**

Kotlin authors introduced a solution which is pretty much a hack/workaround on top of JVM/JS. The idea is: if we can't free the thread while staying inside the function, then... let's return. At a later time we can invoke the function again and jump straight to where we were.

This is essentially how suspending works in Kotlin. The whole point of this complicated bytecode is to allow to jump out (return) of the function at each suspension point and jump back in to each suspension point. Suspension points are places in the code where we may need to suspend - in practice, they're calls to other suspend functions. Also, we use continuations to store the local state: code offset and local variables.

The process is briefly like this:

1. We invoke a suspend function `a`, it invokes `b`, which calls `c`. Our call stack is: `a -> b -> c`
2. `c` suspends, so it stores its state in its continuation and it returns with `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()`.
3. In order to free the thread, we have to return not only from `c`, but from the whole call stack. `b` verifies that `c` returned `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()` and it also returns with the same value. `a` does the same, so now the thread is free to do something else.
4. When we need to resume, we invoke the `c` (without reconstructing the call stack) by passing its continuation.
5. `c` reads its continuation, jumps to the proper offset, loads its local variables and continues as usual.
6. After `c` returns, we do the same with `b` and then with `a`. Each continuation keeps a continuation of the caller, so we always have a chain of all continuations. It fulfills a similar role to the callstack.

So this complicated bytecode is really the code of the function chopped into pieces. Each suspension point is a cut. And we need a way to jump out and jump in from/to each piece.

**Final thoughts**

I suggest to be careful when reading the decompiled code. Decompilers attempt to guess what was the original source code that resulted in a specific bytecode. But the problem is: bytecode of suspending functions is not a result of compiling a regular Java/Kotlin code. It may be even impossible to write a source code which is an equivalent of the analyzed bytecode. For this reason decompilers may be confused and generate a code which is not really correct. If you are interested into such deep details of the language, then I think you should try to read the bytecode directly.

Comment: "which is pretty much a hack/workaround on top of JVM/JS" why JS?

Comment: Anyway, this reminds me of how JavaScript transpilers generate the async/await code for targets that don't support it. In that case, an async function becomes a big switch/case, and each time it is invoked a different number is passed allowing to simulate a "resume"

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Hmm, why not JS? I admit I never looked into the generated JS code for coroutines and I'm not an expert in JS itself. Do you mean Kotlin doesn't have to use this workaround when compiling to JS, and it uses a native async/await functionality? If yes then you are correct - this is specific to JVM only and I'll update my answer.